# How to add a NOTICE file in META-INF of a existing jar?

Tags: java, jar

How to add a NOTICE file in META-INF of a existing jar?

I tried `jar uf jarfilename META-INF NOTICE` but it creates a duplicate META-INF directory instead of updating the existing directory.

Comment: Do you want to do this programatically or from the command line using the jar command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try "META-INFO/NOTICE" or "META-INF NOTICE"?  the former should add the file to the META-INF dir.  the latter will create 2 separate entries in your jar file.

Comment: did you mean I should use jar uf jarfilename META-INF/NOTICE?

Comment: @user441170 - that's exactly what i meant, yes.